# RDF database performances

Tags: java, rdf, jena, virtuoso

I have Java project and I want to use some database for storing RDF data.

I worked with Jena and TDB and the problem came when i tried to insert 100 millions of triplets.. Also the problem was the performance.. While database was growing the inserting of triplets was getting slower and slower.

Then i changed to Virtuoso (still through Jena) and the problem there was the chaotic documentation and also the performance was same as TDB's performance.

My question is if someone used some another DB or has good experience with the databases above to tell me does they support more then 1 Billion triplets and also about the performance.

Comment: Jena is a programming Framework. Jena does include TDB as part of its installation, but Jena can work against many backends, including TDB and Virtuoso. Using the same Jena Framework against multiple backends *may* deliver the same performance regardless of the backend capabilities, due to the way Jena works.

Comment: Multiple benchmarks ([from the LDBC](http://ldbcouncil.org/benchmarks) among others) show Virtuoso performs as well as if not faster than others in the field. You can also find multiple Virtuoso instances live on the web, [a few listed here](https://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores#OpenLink_Virtuoso_v7.2B_-_39.8B.2B_explicit.3B_uncounted_virtual.2Finferred), with multiple billions of triples/quads (not "triplets"). Proper tuning to the environment, as well as appropriate processor and other system resources, are key to performance of any such system.

Comment: TDB is Jena native database. TDB2 has a high-speed bulk loader that loads faster than TDB1. If you explain what performance you are seeing, then maybe people can say whether it is your setup or not. One factor is using SSD - that improves performance as it does for many databases, RDF and otherwise.